# Problem Hair Texture And Eyelashes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, image

While working on the texture of a model I found a problem with hair and eyelashes.

I used Cycles render and nodes to add textures, selecting alpha so it leaves only the textured image of the hair.

The problem is that the texture is fine but it remains with a thin white border.

Picture of a fast render

[image]

Comment: Your image texture is probably unmatched to the alpha map. Try expanding its colors on RGB channels so they are not white outside opaque areas

Comment: how can i expanding color on rgb?